# porque la plantilla ASP.NET Core Web Application no aparece en visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net

**No me aparece la siguiente plantilla en Visual studi0 2019 professional:**

[image: imagen de muestra]

---

**Estas son las que me aparecen a mi:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Tengo estos componentes instalados:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado crear alguna y realizar alguna comparación?

Comment: sí. creé varios proyectos con varias plantillas, sin embargo; el problema era que esperaba ver una pantalla similar.  Con las respuestas de R.Nuñez ya pude elegir la plantilla que requiero.  Muchas gracias por tu aportación.  Saludos.

Comment: ah vale, entendido, éxitos con el proyecto :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viene a ser la misma pero que termina con app, esa es para una web normal y esta la otra que es la app mvc que te deja la plantilla en forma de desarrollo modelo vista controlador

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo R.Nuñez. solo que cuando elijo esa plantilla esperaba ver las opciones (Empty, API, Web Application, Web Application(model-view-controller)), y queria elegir API. ¿Esque se debe elegir de una manera diferente?

Comment: Ahi viene tambien en el listado que estas mostrando es la que termina en web y al final agrega API

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias por el apoyo @R.Nuñez